# Why is my footnote "glued" to the text?

Tags: footnotes, positioning, footmisc

This is the document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=3in, bottom=3in, left=3in, right=3in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\interlinepenalty=10000
\begin{document}
This is first short par\footnote{foot note}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

As you can see the foot note is "glued" to the text and is not a "foot" note any more.. How can I make drop it down to the bottom of the page, where it will look like a real foot note?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I think you might also be interested in the package `footmisc`.

When you use `\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}`, it always puts the footnote as much to the bottom as possible.That means that if your page breaks for whatever reasons (preventing widows or orphans), e.g., 3 lines before it would be full, the footnote is typeset to the bottom as if the page was really full.

The result is you have all the footnotes on all pages at the bottom.

Comment: Loading order: load fixltx2e package before footmisc; if you use stfloats (and \fnbelowfloat), load that package before footmisc, load fnbreak after footmisc, and hyperref und (pdf)lscape afterwards.

Answer (score 14):

You're telling TeX that breaking a page in the middle of paragraphs is infinitely bad. As a result, it's starting a new page after the first paragraph which results in a really underfull page. If you want the page to break after the first paragraph, you should write `\newpage` after it.

I think `\interlinepenalty=10000` is absurd. If you want to control paragraph breaks to that degree, you should simply be explicitly laying out each page.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not wish to use the `footmisc` package for any reason, the following solution from https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=8424 may help:

```
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\vfill\kern -3pt \hrule width 0.4\columnwidth \kern 2.6pt}
```