# How to fix Footnote position at the bottom of the page

Tags: footnotes

`\footnote[1]{\nameref*{8.1.16}` is an अधिकार सूत्र it goes upto `\nameref*{8.3.55}}` \& अङ्गाधिकार (अङ्गस्य)`\footnote[2]{\nameref*{6.4.1}` is an अधिकार सूत्र it goes upto `\nameref*{7.4.97}}`

I am using footnote as shown above. However the footnote appears to be floating and when I don't have much in the page it appears in the middle of the page. I got by so far with \vspace{} but I think there must be a way to position this at the bottom of the page despite whats in the page. Thanks for your help

[image]

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I think

```
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
```

would cure this problem. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4902/why-my-footnote-is-glued-to-the-text).

Comment: In addition, the documentation of the footmisc package is here: https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/footmisc/footmisc.pdf

Comment: If you do not wish to use the `footmisc` package for any reason, the following solution from https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=8424 may help:

    `\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\vfill\kern -3pt \hrule width 0.4\columnwidth \kern 2.6pt}`