# Revisiting middle of page footnote problem

Tags: positioning, footnotes

Configuration: Report document class

Problem: `\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}` is not producing footnotes to the bottom of page as it should, but rather in the middle of a page with few lines of body text.

According to users on the following thread:
[Why is my footnote "glued" to the text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4902/why-is-my-footnote-glued-to-the-text) they suggested adding `\usepackage[]{fixltx2e}`before `\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}` but that did not work either.

Question: Are there other factors causing this problem or what? Here is a MWE as requested below.

```
\documentclass{autemplate} % Offshoot from report document class
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\RequirePackage[backend=biber,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}

\usepackage{fixltx2e}

\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

\begin{document}

Footnotes must be at the bottom of the page at all times.\footnote
{Institution requires footnotes always at the bottom} 
One example is this \autocite[125]{Cross2000}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. You might also want to add to your question how you're including the pdfs etc.

Comment: Thanks for the MWE, but it doesn't show us the problem, neither that custom class you're using. Try with report and tell us if the problem remains. If not, perhaps there is something wrong in the definition of your class.

Comment: I made an adjustment to the MWE above.

Comment: If I remember correctly, `\autocite` is a label that depends of `natbib` or `biblatex`, isn't it? What happens if you use a simple and harmless `\footnote`?

Comment: I use biblatex hence the use of `\autocite`. After stripping out my cls file footnotes were place at the bottom of the text. So I have to work by elimination to see where the problem is.

Comment: where can we get a copy of your `autemplate` class file?  my guess is it’s patching `\footnote` in such a way that the `footmisc` package can’t perform _its_ hack to make the bottom placement.