# Sidenote in mdframed environment, Tufte-LateX

Tags: footnotes, mdframed, tufte

I'm looking for a way to put sidenotes in mdframed environment on Tufte-LaTeX. Text would be refered to inside the box, and the note lying in the margin.

I have already found a fancy way to do an equivalent thing with footnotes in an article document class ([Place a footnote in an environment in the bottom of the page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388960/place-a-footnote-in-an-environment-in-the-bottom-of-the-page)). Here is my minimal working version for this case :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % Necessary for the toggle 
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed} % Required for creating the definition box


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   THEOREM STYLES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\definecolor{thmcolor}{rgb}{0.71,0.14,0.07}

% Boxed/framed environments
\newtheoremstyle{redThm}  % Theorem style name
{0pt}                     % Space above
{0pt}                     % Space below
{\normalfont}             % Body font
{}                        % Indent amount
{\small\bf\sffamily\color{thmcolor}}% % Theorem head font
{\;}                      % Punctuation after theorem head
{0.25em}                  % Space after theorem head
{\small\sffamily\color{thmcolor}\thmname{#1}\nobreakspace\thmnumber{#2}% Theorem text (e.g. Theorem 2.1)
    \thmnote{\nobreakspace\the\thm@notefont\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}---\nobreakspace#3.}} % Optional theorem note

\theoremstyle{redThm}
\newtheorem{defn}{Définition}[section]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DEFINITION OF COLORED BOX
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Definition box
\newmdenv[skipabove=7pt,
skipbelow=7pt,
rightline=false,
leftline=true,
topline=false,
bottomline=false,
linecolor=thmcolor,
innerleftmargin=5pt,
innerrightmargin=5pt,
innertopmargin=0pt,
leftmargin=0cm,
rightmargin=0cm,
linewidth=4pt,
innerbottommargin=0pt]{vBar}    

\newtoggle{indefintion}
\togglefalse{indefintion}
\pretocmd{\footnote}{\iftoggle{indefintion}{\stepcounter{footnote}}{\relax}}{}{}

% Creates the environment ---> @iacopo suggestion <---
\newenvironment{definition}[1]{%
  \savenotes
  \begin{vBar}\begin{defn}
      \toggletrue{indefintion}
      \renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
    \item[\hskip \labelsep]
      {\bfseries #1}}{\end{defn}\end{vBar}
  \togglefalse{indefintion}
\spewnotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
  My definition.\footnote{My footnote.}
\end{definition}

\bigskip

My text.\footnote{Core text footnote}.  

\end{document}
```

Changing footnotes by sidenotes isn't enough to get it work in a tufte-latex document class : I would like to adapt the /savenote, /spewnote trick to sidenotes, while keeping a consistent numbering inside the page with the toggle trick (which allows not to increment the counter when there is no sidenote in the theorem).