# how to use `\marginnote` in `mdframed` environment? (follow up)

Tags: mdframed, double-sided, tufte, marginnote

I need to have a line on the **INNER** margin in a double-sided tufte-document. There was a close question and it has [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121315/ho-do-i-draw-a-line-on-the-inner-margin-in-a-double-sided-document). That answer is perfect. Their output is: 
[image]
(You see the line on the INNER part of the page)

The difference is that I use `tufte-book` class, but that example is for an `article` class. As soon as I use `\marginnote{Hello}` in this code snippet LaTex gives a mistake `! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.`

```
\begin{mdframed}[style=MDFStyGrayBar]
\lipsum
%\marginnote{Hello}
\lipsum
\end{mdframed}
```

(for the full code shamelessly stolen from the link, see below)

I wonder *how to use `\marginnote` in `mdframed` environment*, if possible. My search led to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402930/sidenote-in-mdframed-environment-tufte-latex), that also doesn't have any answer.

I also have quite a number of `\marginnote`, `marginfigure` and `figure*` floats (with some tikz stuffing). I assume they all work the same, so I hope they will work as soon as the problem will be solved for at least one of them.

Any code modifications are welcome, as I still don't understand how that solution works anyway (I am freaking out as I see @ and code around it).

```
\documentclass[twoside,symmetric,notoc,justified]{tufte-book}%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgf,caption,calc}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}


\geometry{
  %showframe,
  paperwidth=145mm,
  paperheight=215mm,
  inner=16mm,
  outer=10mm,
  top=10mm,
  bottom=40mm,
  marginparsep=3mm,
  marginparwidth=40mm,
  includemp,
  includehead,
}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed} 
\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*\if@mdf@pageodd@bar{%
 \zref@refused{mdf@pagelabel-\the\value{mdf@zref@counter}}%
 \ifodd\zref@extract{mdf@pagelabel-\the\value{mdf@zref@counter}}%
                    {mdf@pagevalue}%
    \setlength\mdf@rightmargin@length{\mdf@outermargin@length}%
    \setlength\mdf@leftmargin@length{\mdf@innermargin@length}%
    \mdfsetup{hidealllines=true,leftline=true}%
 \else
    \setlength\mdf@rightmargin@length{\mdf@innermargin@length}%
    \setlength\mdf@leftmargin@length{\mdf@outermargin@length}%
    \mdfsetup{hidealllines=true,rightline=true}%
 \fi%
}
\newrobustcmd*\changepageodd{\let\if@mdf@pageodd\if@mdf@pageodd@bar}
\makeatother
\mdfdefinestyle{MDFStyGrayBar}{%
    linecolor=gray,
    backgroundcolor=white,
    %
    outerlinewidth=5pt,
    %
    topline=false,
    bottomline=false,
    rightline=false,
    leftline=true,
    %
    innertopmargin=4pt, %\baselineskip
    innerbottommargin=8pt,
    innerrightmargin=3pt,
    innerleftmargin=3pt,
    %
    skipabove=\topskip,
    skipbelow=\topskip,
    settings={\changepageodd}
}
\usepackage{showframe,lipsum}
\begin{document}

\noindent Some normal text.
\begin{mdframed}[style=MDFStyGrayBar]
\lipsum
%\marginnote{Hello}
\lipsum
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Generally you cannot, `\marginnote` is a float and it cannot escape the mdframed boxes. I don;t quite understand what you are mentioning about a line, please update your question to something that are clearer to understand. Also don't put your questions into the bounty.

Comment: @dalief, sorry, I was not sure. Then the hint -box asked me for the clarification for the answerer, I did my best. Should I update my question by adding possible ways to resolve it (or at least the ways that would work or me)?

Comment: You should at least update your question so it is clearer what you are asking. Note that the site favours clear explicit questions, not "please do this for me" questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\marginnote` definition of the tufte-book class is based on `\marginpar`. This is a float and it won't work inside a mdframed environment.

You can switch to the `\marginnote` definition of the `marginnote` package, which is not a float. Be aware that this completly overwrite the tufte-definition. So none of the tufte settings or options will apply:

```
\documentclass[twoside,symmetric,notoc,justified]{tufte-book}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}


\let\marginnote\someundefinedcommand
\usepackage{marginnote}

\begin{document}


\noindent Some normal text.
\begin{mdframed}
blblb 
\marginnote{Hello}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I accept it as the answer. Unfortunately, this solution does not allow to place figures and TikZ pictures in the '\marginpar' environment redefined like that. I have a lot of stuff like that. It looks like I have to find another way to emphasize several paragraphs. This solution brings me more problems than this particular one resolved.

Comment: It should be no problem to add a tikz picture inside a \marginnote.  And you can add figures, if you don't use the figure environment.