# \usepackage[bottom]{footmisc} does not fix footnotes at bottom of beamer slide

Tags: beamer, footnotes, footmisc

I'm having difficulty getting citations at the bottom of Beamer to be actually at the bottom. Using the command `\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}` from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4902/why-is-my-footnote-glued-to-the-text)
doesn't do anything.

It actually makes the font of the footnote larger, which makes me think I have another package which it overwrites. 
What should I look for in the .tex to fix this?
I'm using our university beamer template so it's a bit messy to post, but I can if nobody has a suggestion. Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: It is probably due to the `columns` environment, try using the `frame` option of `\footnote`. See here for instance https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86757/141947

Comment: Any news on this question, did you manage to solve your problem ?

Comment: Thanks for checking in @BambOo. I never fixed it, and ended up just not adding citations. If anyone figures it out, I'd be curious!

Comment: I answered [another question of the same type recently](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/544876/citations-in-columns-with-an-itemize-environment-and-an-image-side-by-side-beam/545100#545100), without using `footmisc` as your question mentions this package specifically, I will have a look at it to see if a solution with this package is also possible. Note that the `bottom` option does not seem to be made for `beamer`

Comment: This package redefines footnotes in addition to `beamer`'s own modifications. Without your own code, I cannot test any solution, but I would say one of the ones I propose in the other question should work. Can you add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) ?

Comment: `footmisc` seems to break footnotes in all kind of document classes. beamer is apparently one of them (although at least `\footnote[frame]{…}` seems to remain working, but i had problems with it in koma too. i would recommend not using it if not absolutely necessary.